# Why does my computer hang during the POST memory test?

Tags: memory

I have a problem with my P35-GS4 motherboard and its memory(2x1GB Crossair + 2x2GB OCZ DDR2 400). More specifically when I boot my computer it hangs during the POST memory test where it says:

```
Memory test:
```

and only shows:

```
Memor
```

It stays like that for 5-7 minutes before finally continuing with the BIOS finding my hard disk and then booting the system. I thought it is a memory problem. I ran memtest for about 6-7 hours and have this image:

[image: memtest results link]

I've tried a lot of things. I removed each RAM module (two modules each time since it's dual layer) and even switched its position up on my motherboard. I removed one hard disk every time and booted my PC but whatever I did the BIOS would hang at the same spot.

When my machine eventually boots everything is fine without any unexpected events.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Do a binary search through your memory by removing half and running memtest86+.  If the installed set tests clear (I've had it take up to a *week* of repeated passes to catch faulty memory), install the other half of memory.  If you hit the fault, remove half of the memory and recursively repeat the process until only a single DIMM is installed.  Alternatively, you could just replace all of the memory and run memtest86+.

If memtest86+ reports an error on both halves of a given population or an error after replacing all of the memory, something is wrong with the motherboard traces, memory controller, external caches, or the CPU itself.